# Loop and register the result of every update

Tags: loops, sas

I am working with random variables and have binomial results, but I can only get this binomial results if i re-run every single code again to get different results. So, how can I loop 100 times and register every result in a data table after?

```
%macro freq_loop(n);
    %do i = 1 %to &n;
        call `streamini`(i);
        data freq_results_&i;
            set assets_data;
            output;
        run;
        `proc` freq data=freq_results_&i;
            tables Data / `nocum` `nocol` `norow`;
        run;
    %end;
%mend freq_loop;
%freq_loop(100);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou5Ft.png)

the binomial results are shown in the freq but every loop is the same result cause is not re-running the codes.

---

Edited in from an answer posted:

```
do Asset= 1 to 200;
  if Asset>0 then do;
    S1 = RAND("uniform");
    S2 = RAND("uniform");
    S3 = RAND("uniform");
    S4 = RAND("uniform");
    S5 = RAND("uniform");
    `Zi` = RAND("uniform");
    end;
    output;
    end;
run; 

`proc` print data=assets;
run;

data combined_data;
  merge original_data assets; 
run;

`proc` print data=combined_data;
run;

data assets_xi; set combined_data;
Xi = (F1*S1 + F2*S2 + F3*S3 + F4*S4 + F5*S5) + 
  `(Zi * SQRT`  (1 - F1**2+ F2**2 + F3**2 + F4**2 +F5**2));
run;

`proc` print data=assets_xi;
run;

data `assets_ui`;set assets_xi;
    do `Ui = pdf`("Normal", Xi, 0, 1);
        output;
    end;
run;

`proc` print data=`assets_ui`;
run;

data pd_table;
    length `RatingNum` $3. PD1-PD5 8.;
    input `RatingNum` $ PD1-PD5;
    `datalines`;
1 0.0000 0.0300 0.1300 0.2400 0.3400
2 0.0200 0.0600 0.1400 0.2500 0.3500
3 0.0500 0.1300 0.2200 0.3300 0.4600
4 0.1600 0.4300 0.7500 1.1400 1.5400
5 0.6300 1.9300 3.4600 4.9900 6.4300
6 3.3400 7.8000 11.7500 14.8900 17.3500
;
run;

data assets_pd; set `assets_ui`; 
`proc` format;
    value $`rating_to_num`
    'AAA'=1
    'AA'=2
    'A'=3
    'BBB'=4
    'BB'=5
    'B'=6;
run;

data assets_pd_rating;
    set assets_pd;
    `RatingNum` = input(put(Rating, $`rating_to_num`.), 8.);
    drop Rating;
run;

`proc` print data=assets_pd_rating;
run;

data rating_pd; set pd_table;
`Average_PDs`= (sum(PD1+PD2+PD3+PD4+PD5)/5);
run;

data assets_pd_horizon; 
set assets_pd_rating;
    if `RatingNum`=1 then PD_horizon= (0.148+6)/100;
    else if `RatingNum`=2 then PD_horizon= (0.164+6)/100;
    else if `RatingNum`=3 then PD_horizon= (0.238+6)/100;
    else if `RatingNum`=4 then PD_horizon= (0.804+6)/100;
    else if `RatingNum`=5 then PD_horizon= (3.488+6)/100;
    else if `RatingNum`=6 then PD_horizon= (11.026+6)/100;
    output;
run;

`proc` print data=assets_pd_horizon;
run;

data assets_pd_rating_default;
    length default $3;
    set assets_pd_horizon;
    retain Default;
    if `Ui` < PD_horizon then Default='No';
    else Default= 'Yes';
    output;
run;

`proc` print data=assets_pd_rating_default;
run;

`proc` freq data=assets_pd_rating_default;
    tables Default / `nocum nocol norow`;
run;

data assets_default;
    set assets_pd_rating_default;
    if _N_ < 201 or _N_ > 2010 then output;
run;

data `assets_defaultNum`; set assets_default;
    if Default='Yes' then `DefaultNum` = 1;
    else `DefaultNum` = 0;
run;

`proc` print data=`assets_defaultNum`;
run;

`proc` freq data=`assets_DefaultNum`;
run;

`proc` freq data=`assets_DefaultNum`;
    tables `DefaultNum` / `nocum nocol norow`;
run;
```

This is my whole code set. So I have 200 assets with ratings and F1 to F5 variables from an excel imported to `SAS`, then i created the S1 to S5 and `Zi` random variables, then i did all my calculations to get the Pd_horizon, and default probability. So things are just to clean and organize my data but the idea is to get 100 loops and get 100 different results from the amount of yes=1 and no=0 default probabilities of the 200 assets every time i re-run the codes.Adding the codes to my original macro codes didn't work, those loops needs to be registered in a new data table so i can graph it later.

Comment: What's random about that?  You're running the same `proc freq` on the same dataset 100 times, of course it's the same.  What do you actually want to do?

Comment: I have random variables in the data table which are used to generate binomial results of Yes=1 and No=0 after formulating default possibility of 200 assets. Those binomial results are going to change every time I re-run because of the random variables. I need to repeat this process 100 times to create a impact of correlation on the default distribution.  That's why i need a loop 100 but it needs to re-run everything for it to work and have different results in every loop.

Comment: Can you change the code above to include that then? Right now the code above is just doing a proc freq on the entire dataset 100 times, which will never have different results.  Show us what you're doing and we can help.  Do you want to take a *random sample* of the larger dataset each time, for example?

Comment: I posted my whole code set in the answers so you can see and probably understand more what I am having issues with. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
%macro freq_loop(n);
    %do i = 1 %to &n;

        call streamini(i);
        data freq_results_&i;
            set assets_data;
            output;
        run;

        proc freq data=freq_results_&i;
            tables Data / nocum nocol norow out=FreqCount;
        run;

        %if &i=1 %then %do;

            data output_results;
                if 0 then
                    set freq_results_&i;
                stop;
            run;

        %end;

        proc append 
            base=output_results 
            data=FreqCount
            force;
        run;

    %end;
%mend freq_loop;

%freq_loop(100);
```

Comment: Looks like is not generating any results.  I'm getting: The table "WORK.OUTPUT_RESULTS" cannot be opened because it does not contain any columns.

Comment: I see I made a mistake. 

this generate the work.output_results in the first loop (i=1)
     data output_results;
                if 0 then
                    set freq_results_&i;
                stop;
            run;
I used a wrong dataset